# .htaccess redirect rule permanent domain change

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, basically I have changed the domain name from Domain1.info to Domain2.com

Another thing that I have changed, is the rule for urls inside website

- old url structure: `www.Domain1.info/lang/page-name.html`
- new url structure: `www.Domain2.com/lang/page-name`

I have added the code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
```

which successfully redirect me from old to new domain, but I want to get rid of the `.html` ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, just exclude the `.html` part from the first matched group:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
```

Comment: not working. Should this be placed on the .htaccess from domain2 ?

Comment: @MihaelaGurgu, you just need to replace your second line with this one. The idea is that `$` = *what was matched inside `()`*

Comment: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

With this I still get that .html which will result in 404 error on landing domain :(

Still, I checked on: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it resulted what should be... still, in fact is not redirecting properly

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your regex to match only part before `.html`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# to redirect .html URLs
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# to redirect other URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```